Integrating New URL Segments in CodeIgniter Without Disruption
I've developed an application for a client that currently uses the URL structure https://project.es/index. Now, they need to switch to https://project.es/apps/other_segment/index.
I've adjusted base_url in config.php, updated .htaccess for RewriteBase, and modified routes in routes.php. However, each fix seems to break another part of the application.
How can I seamlessly integrate the /apps/other_segment/ structure into my URLs without causing errors or extensive modifications?
Configuration:
.htaccess:
RewriteBase /
config.php:
$config['base_url'] = '``http://www.project.es/``';
routes.php:
$route['default_controller'] = 'login/index';
$route['404_override'] = 'notfound';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
$route['(\w{2})/loginadmin'] = "loginadmin/index";
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
I'm using MY_Lang.phpfor language management, but unsure if it's causing issues.
Despite adjustments, fixing one problem often creates new ones.

you have to change base_url to https://project.es/apps/other_segment/index and also RewriteBase to RewriteBase /apps/other_segment/. What errors do you see?

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.project.es Port 8080
Maybe the problem is related also to the idiom structure on the url. Above is the error message after apply ur changes
Error log says about multiple redirections

Look at the logs files, normally in application/logs to realize the error.
